# Validate classes (hydra-core lists) with pydantic

Tags: python, validation, pydantic, fb-hydra

## 1. Context

How to validate a specific class in pydantic?

I'm using [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) to validate yaml list parameters parsed by [hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/intro/), to later be passed to modeling routines. The problem is that the hydra dictionary contains not a list of values, but a class that contains those values. How can I validate those params?

## 2. Example

In the following example, there are 2 files:

- `cfg.yaml` containing the parameters to be validated
- `main.py` containing the instructions to load and validate `cfg.yaml`

### 2.1 Config File `cfg.yaml`

```
params_list:
  - 10
  - 0
  - 20
```

### 2.2 Parser/Validator file `main.py`

```
import hydra
import pydantic
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
from typing import List

class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    params_list: List[int]

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="cfg.yaml")
def go(cfg: DictConfig):
    parsed_cfg = Test(**cfg)
    print(parsed_cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
```

## 3. Problem

When executing `python3 main.py` the following error arises

> value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

That is because hydra has a specific class for dealing with lists, called `omegaconf.listconfig.ListConfig`, which can be checked by adding

```
print(type(cfg['params_list']))
```

right after the `go()` function definition.

## 4. Guidance

I know that I probably have to tell `pydantic` to validate this specific thing, but I just don't know exactly how.

- [Here](https://www.madelyneriksen.com/blog/validated-container-types-python-pydantic) are provided some tips, but it seems to much for the task I guess.
- Another idea is to create a generic type for the data attribute (like `params_list: Generic`) and then use the validator decorator to transform it to a list, something along the lines:

```
class ParamsList(pydantic.BaseModel):
  params_list: ???????? #i don't know that to do here
  @p.validator("params_list")
  @classmethod
    def validate_path(cls, v) -> None:
        """validate if it's a list"""
        if type(list(v)) != list:
            raise TypeError("It's not a list. Make it become a list")
        return list(v)
```

**Help!: Any idea on how to solve it?**

## How to Recreate Example

1. In a folder add files described in sections 2.1 and 2.2.
2. Also create a `requirements.txt` file with the packages `pydantic` and `hydra-core`
3. After creating and activating the env, run `python3 main.py`

Comment: Would you consider calling `OmegaConf.to_container` on the `DictConfig` object before passing the data into the `Test` class? For example: `parsed_cfg = Test(**OmegaConf.to_container(cfg))`.

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic doesn't accept the DictConfig format. When you try to parse the hydra config with the pydantic model, you must first convert the DictConfig to a native Python Dict. You do this with `OmegaConf.to_object(cfg)`.

I assume you use Python 3.10 or higher. Note the use of `version_base="1.2"` to get the latest hydra version.

This should work:

```
import hydra
import pydantic
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf

class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    params_list: list[int]


@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="cfg.yaml", version_base="1.2")
def go(cfg: DictConfig):
    print(cfg)
    d_cfg = OmegaConf.to_object(cfg)
    parsed_cfg = Test(**d_cfg)
    print(parsed_cfg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
```